# How to make loop and exception inside flatmap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am having a requirement where I have to loop over a list and do create `Map[String,String]`. Here the header has values as list like below:

```
val headersMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
try {
  val payloadHeaders = collectorPayload.headers
  for (values <- payloadHeaders.toList) {
    for (value <- values) {
      val header = value.split(":").map(_.trim)
      headersMap += (header(0) -> header(1))
      headersMap += ("Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    }
  }
} catch {
  case e: Exception => {
    logger.error("Collector Payload extraction error with : " + e.getMessage)
  }
}
```

Is there any better way to handle this any map or flatMap way?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use mutable collections or variables (just pretend they don't exist util you run into a use case where you *positively* cannot do without them ... it won't be soon).
Also generally avoid using loops (because they kinda assume and promote mutability and side effects), you'll need them even less often than mutable collections.

```
   collectorPayload
     .headers
     .iterator
     .flatMap(_.split(":").map(_.trim))
     .map { case Array(a,b) => a -> b }
     .toMap + ("Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `collect` here just in case the **Array** doesn't have two elements. Or would you rather let it crash than silently discarding values?

Comment: I dunno, the OP has a `try/catch` around it, so, I am assuming, it's the latter ...

Comment: Thanks for you answer .I have a question what is values in flatmap you have used ?In the loop it was to store each element

Comment: I does the same thing your loop does. You may find it helpful to run each statement separately in a repl one by one and see exactly what transformations are happening at each step (replace `.iterator` with `.toList` to get the results pretty printed).

Comment: Yes I understood that part.My question in inside flatMap what is the values is about i see error when I use flatMap(_.values)

Comment: @Kumar Padhy sorry, I misread your loop. Fixed it now, see of it works better?

Comment: As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentioned we do not have always 2 elements and the the code I used to append so that if any error still we will have half constructed data but if I use the solution Dima suggested it always go to exception with no value in headerMap.I think something to be done in Array(a,b)

Comment: No, your code would throw two if there are no two elements ... Or do you mean, you have _more_ than two? That's weird, but whatever. Just replace `.map` with `.collect` of you want to swallow those errors.